# How to change VS Code color picker color code type?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the latest Mac version of Visual Studio Code and I can't figure out how to make the built-in color picker default to hex values when I'm editing a CSS value color. Currently, it's defaulting to rgba values. The Color Picker document shows it displaying hex values. I opened my settings and searched for "color" and "color picker" I did not see a pertinent setting. How do I change the default to hex values?

[Visual Studio Code now has a really useful color picker built-in](https://mspoweruser.com/visual-studio-code-now-really-useful-color-picker-built/)
[Color Picker](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_color-picker)

Comment: It will default to whatever the current color mode (hex, rgba, hsl,...) that is being hovered over.  You can click on the top bar where the color value is listed to cycle through the various color modes.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! This "click on the top bar where the color value is listed to cycle through the various color modes" was not obvious. :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To switch color mode just click the bar with color code.

[image]

But according to [this ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31644) you can not switch to HEX when opacity is not set to maximum.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh. That's the problem with UIs these days. Everything is hidden. Why would anyone think to click on the bar to change the format for the value? Thanks.

Comment: How can I do this without switching the actual color from rgb to hex? I want the value to remain rgb and the color picker to display the hex value, but clicking the bar converts the value to hex. I'm not interested in the picker functionality, just the color preview